# cómo usar los operadores cortocircuito con la variable let?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

Fue algo que me sucedió utilizando las variables de tipo let, normalmente utilizaba los operadores cortocircuito dentro de una variable de tipo var eje:

`var object1 = object1 || {};`

pero me tope con que si intento realizar la misma operación con let la consola me arroja :

`Uncaught ReferenceError: object1 in not defined(...)`

alguien sabe la razón o como utilizar este tipo de operadores dentro de las variables let o se debe seguir usando var.

**Posdata: el editor de código webstorm me arroja que se debe usar let en lugar de var para evitar la elevación de variables o posibles coliciones**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te estás encontrado con un problema que se explica en la página de MDN para [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) en la sección "[Zona muerta temporal y errores con let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let#Zona_muerta_temporal_y_errores_con_let)", y que se debe a las diferencias entre `let` y [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var). En particular a dos de ellas:

1. **`let` no permite la redeclaración de una variable con el mismo nombre en el mismo ámbito**. Algo que `var` sí que permite (básicamente se considerará una asignación, o se ignorará si no se inicia la variable).

   Se lanzaría un error de tipo `TypeError`. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   let a = 1;
   let a = 2; // Error! el identificador ya se ha declarado

   let b = 1;
   var b = 2; // Error! el identificador ya se ha declarado

   var c = 1;
   var c = 2; // No problem, el valor de c será 2
   ```
2. **En ECMAScript 6, `let` no eleva la variable a la parte supertior del bloque.** Eso quiere decir que no puedes usar la variable antes de declararla, algo que sí puedes hacer con `var`

   Se lanzaría un error de tipo `ReferenceError`. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   a = 1;      // Error! referencia a variable no definida
   let a = 2; 

   b = 1;      // No problem
   var b = 2;
   ```

Dependiendo del ámbito en el que estés realizando la operación de cortocircuito, te dará un error o el otro (en tu caso el segundo), pero básicamente el error se va a deber por uno u otro. Por ejemplo, al hacer:

```
let a = a || 1;
```

Te vas a encontrar con uno de los siguientes problemas:

- La variable `a` ya estaba definida: error de sintáxis, `let` no te permite redeclarar variables (1).
- La variabla `a` no estaba definida: error de referencia, estás intentando usar `a` en una asignación antes de que haya sido declarada (2).

Como ves, sea la situación que sea `let` te va a dar fallo. Por eso para operador cortocircuito debes usar `var` en su lugar.

Comment: Alvaro me quedo clarisimo, excelente respuesta.